# Migrate Google App Engine project to newer version (with Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a Google Web Toolkit (GWT) application (Java) that is running on Google App Engine. The app is running fine, but i haven't touched the code in a while. Now i need to modify some things, but i can't get Eclipse/AppEngine to deploy the project any more.
I have reinstalled Eclipse, downloaded and installed tge GWT and Google Cloud Platfrom plugins. And the Cloud SDK.

I'm using Eclipse Mars/2 but i am willing to do this from command line of necessary.

My project is now GWT-compiling fine and it runs locally with the development server.

What i fail to do is get the link up with my existing AppEngine project.
The Google Cloud Platform button only proposes "Create New Project" and the "Deploy to App Engine Standard" option is greyed out.
What do i need to configure to link the GWT app to my existing AppEngine project and deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Project > Properties > Google Cloud Platform > App Engine Deployment:

Refresh the list.

Make sure it is linked to account and new version number is psecified.
=> Apply.

Now "Google Cloud Platform > Deploy to App Engine Standard" is available.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed the [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse), you should be able to right-click on the project and select *Configure > Convert to App Engine Standard Project*.  Basically that removes traces of the older GPE configuration and installs the *App Engine Standard* facet and configures the App Engine runtime libraries.